# node.js sending POST requests not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to send a post request but It is not sending. I dont get output in the console log of the browser.

My node server.js is running in x.x.x.x:8000 then I connect it with my client.html. x.x.x.x:8000/client.html

Here is my node.js server.

```
function handler (req, res) {

  var filepath = '.' + req.url;
  if (filepath == './')
      filepath = './client.html';

  var extname = path.extname(filepath);
  var contentType = 'text/html';

  switch(extname){
    case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
    case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
  }

  path.exists(filepath, function (exists){
        if (exists){
            fs.readFile(filepath, function(error, content){
                if(error){
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    res.end();
                }
                else{
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end();
        }
  });


}
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE - I'm using ajax call and sending request to COMMAND.php

```
 $.post( 
                '/var/www/COMMAND.php', 
                { cmd: "OUT" }, 
                function( data ){  

               console.log(data);



                });
```

PHP COMMAND.php - This writes to the the named pipe in linux. When it is done writing it echo success.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['cmd'] === 'OUT') {
    $con = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "w");
    fwrite($con, "OUT\n");
    fclose($con);
    echo "SUCCESS";
    exit;
}

?>
```

Why is it not sending any post requests to COMMAND.php? Is there any way for me to call COMMAND.php and execute the commands in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because NodeJS runs JS, not PHP. Also, unlike Apache which has a built-in file handling, in NodeJS, you need to build code or use an existing library to route your urls to files.

As for your question, it's either you:

- Setup another server to execute that PHP. Your AJAX is calling to your NodeJS server. You could route that request from NodeJS to your PHP server (Apache or whatever), basically making NodeJS act like a proxy.
- Or create code in JavaScript *for NodeJS* that runs a similar routine as your PHP script, and you won't need PHP or another server anymore.

Comment: Thanks, When I change '/var/www/COMMAND.php' in my Javascript to http://x.x.x.x/COMMAND.php it works it writes to the named pipe but I'm getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://x.x.x.x/COMMAND.php. Origin http://x.x.x.x:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @Defyleiti That would be due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).